# Formik - Show ErrorMessage on Blur

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik, yup

On the code below there is a text input that shows an error message when:

- type invalid email (or leave blank) and hit enter
- type invalid email (or leave blank) and blur (or clicking outside)

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const TextInput = ({ value, handleChange }) => (
  <input
    type="text"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
  />
);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .required('Email is required.')
          .email('Email is invalid.'),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {({ setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          <div>
            <Field
              type="text"
              name="email"
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                console.log(value);
                setFieldValue('email', value);
              }}
            />
            <ErrorMessage name="email">
              {(error) => <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>{error}</div>}
            </ErrorMessage>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Now I want to keep the same behavior when doing the following change:

from

```
<Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    onChange={({target:{value}}) => {
        console.log(value);
        setFieldValue("email", value);
    }}
/>
```

to:

```
<Field
    component={TextInput}
    name="email"
    handleChange={(value) => {
        console.log(value);
        setFieldValue("email", value);
    }}
/>
```

I mean, basically I'm changing from: `type="text"` to `component={TextInput}` which is basically a text input as you can see above.

After doing that change the error happens when:

- [SUCCESS] type invalid email (or leave blank) and hit enter

but not when:

- [FAIL] type invalid email (or leave blank) and blur (or clicking outside)

Do you know how can I get the error displayed on the second situation?

I'm looking for a standard way to do it and not tricky workarounds.

Here you have a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-yup-example-uhdg-yqm8jd) you can play with and if you want you can post your forked one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is to pass `name` and `id` between the component and wrapper, otherwise, Formik has no relationship and therefore no knowledge of what to error.

[Here's a fork](https://react-formik-yup-example-uhdg-myw4fu.stackblitz.io)

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const TextInput = ({ value, handleChange, name, id }) => (
  <Field
    id={id} // <- adding id
    name={name} // <- adding name
    type="text"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange} // You don't need to capture the event, you've already done the work in the wrapper
  />
);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .required('Email is required.')
          .email('Email is invalid.'),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {({ setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          <div>
            <Field
              component={TextInput}
              id="email" // <- id
              name="email" // <- name
              handleChange={e => {
                const value = e.target.value;
                console.log(value);
                setFieldValue('email', value);
              }}
            />
            <ErrorMessage name="email">
              {(error) => <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>{error}</div>}
            </ErrorMessage>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```